# Show first row on top when table becomes visible

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/IwyleQCLz8TtsmB3qsoo?p=preview) there's a table with two buttons Show/Hide. If you scroll the table to the bottom line, then click Hide, and then click Show again, the table will still show the bottom line. I need that anytime the Show button is clicked, the table should show the first line at the top. Is this feasible?

HMTL

```
<div style="width:300px;height:80px;border:1px solid gray;overflow-y:auto"
    ng-show="show">
     <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td>{{item.col}}</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 <br>        
 <button ng-click="show=false">Hide</button>
 <button ng-click="show=true">Show</button>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctl', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = [ {col:"aaa"}, {col:"bbb"} , {col:"ccc"}, 
                     {col:"aaa2"}, {col:"bbb2"} , {col:"ccc2"}, 
                     {col:"aaa2"}, {col:"bbb2"} , {col:"ccc2"} ];
    $scope.show = true;

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `ng-show` to `ng-if` then it will re-create the table instead of changing the visibility so the scroll will be back at the top.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tpmkRnLtthgdpQFJUz7t?p=preview)